# Which yeast/bacteria produce no, or little alcohol (like Bionade)?

Tags: fermentation, alcohol-content, bacteria

Producing a variety of different beer styles, we are able make adult friends happy, however children are left out :(

I therefore wanted to ask if somebody knows where to look for yeasts that are not producing alcohol, yet ferment a wort?

On Wikipedia one can read about this commercial product [Bionade (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionade), which suggest that some person at a brewery (after claimed years of experimenting) was able to cultivate a mico-organism (not really a yeast but a bacteria) that instead of generating alcohol, generates gluconic acid.

> He experimented for eight years in a bathroom laboratory, spending
>   €1.5 million of the brewery owner Peter Kowalsky's money. He isolated
>   a strain of bacteria capable of converting the sugar that normally
>   becomes alcohol into nonalcoholic gluconic acid, which he used to
>   ferment the new drink.[3]

Is there maybe an non-proprietary, open source version of this bacteria?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are some sub species of lactobacillus that consume sugar and create latic acid, but don't create ethanol. (homofermentative)

Many others can be forced to only produce acid and cO2 by depriving them of oxygen.

http://www.milkthefunk.com/wiki/Lactobacillus

Is a great one page resource on the subject.

*Has far as the bactiera you mention I'm not aware of any public version.*

DYI Bionade:
https://www.bionade.de/en/production-process/

Humorously they do not specify what the bacteria is.

The genius is Gluconobacter

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluconobacter